# Ошибка 404 при попытке отредактировать сообщение

Tags: дефект, статус-не-воспроизводится, правки

Пытаюсь [отредактировать сообщение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/314734). При нажатии на ссылку ["править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/314734/edit) ловлю ошибку 404. Редактирование других сообщений работает.

---

Ещё при попытке отправить этот вопрос выползает ошибка:

> Тело вопроса не отвечает стандартам качества проекта. Убедитесь, что в нем полностью описана проблема, а также Ваши решения, в грамматически правильной форме.

Comment: Не воспроизвелось

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev Похоже, уже починилось. Видимо, какой-то временный глюк был.

Comment: Можно повесить [status-completed] =)

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev Такой тег может повесить только ромб.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня при попытке отредактировать возникает 500 ошибка, если проверять в инструментах разработчика.
Обращение идет вот сюда:
`https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/314734/edit-inline?_=1427967086105`

Comment: У меня права редактирования инлайн ещё нет. :) Забавно, что ошибки разные, хотя URL практически один и тот же.

Comment: По вашей ссылке действительно 404-я ошибка, забыл это подтвердить.

Comment: У меня работает и так, и так — но может быть у меня слишком много прав.