# Редактирование вопроса не найдено

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, правки

При попытке редактировать сообщение "[Как обойти проблему очерёдности создания таблиц с внешними ключами ссылающиеся друг на друга?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/69279/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%91%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4)" возникает ошибка:

> Не удалось загрузить сообщение

Если попытаться перейти на [отдельную страницу редактирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/69279/edit), а не пользоваться инлайновым редактированием, то отображается ошибка **404**:

> Страница не найдена
>
> We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.

Истории у поста не видно, да и каких-то особенностей тоже. Что за мистика?

P. S. Похожий баг уже возникал при редактировании *ответа:* "[Ошибка 404 при попытке отредактировать сообщение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-404-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)". Он "исчез сам" и сопровождён меткой [статус-не-воспроизводится](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f). По-моему, пора уже расправиться с багом. :)

Comment: Уже исправили. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26443985#26443985

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Поздравляю, вы нашли секретный баг! За него вы получите секретную шляпу.

Для получения шляпы необходимо, чтобы на вопросе и ответе было по 10 голосов.

---

Кстати, если посмотреть в историю правок вопроса, то там вообще пусто.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/69279/revisions

Попытка посмотреть первую версию вопроса:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/69279/1

Похоже, что в базе данных есть только отрендеренный текст, но нет исходника в markdown.

Comment: При внесении правок через API, в частности через приложения Stack Exchange для iOS / Android, наличие исходника вроде бы не требуется. Советую попробовать отредактировать таким образом (я не могу, для этого требуется 2000 реп., поскольку API не поддерживает предложенных правок).

Comment: @NormalHuman: приложение отвечает мне "This error has been logged"